Laravel - Filament: get distinct values of a relationship column
I am using the Form Builder of Laravel Filament 3.x where I want to select only  clients who have distinct first names.
I tried this but it displays all the clients, including those who have the same first_name:
 Select::make('client_id')
      ->relationship('client', 'first_name', 
           fn (Builder $query) => $query->distinct()),

Any hints on how to achieve the goal ?
Here is the Form Builder reference.
Here is the Elquent Builder.

You can try groupBy that gives you same result with distinct while using query builder
Select::make('client_id')
  ->relationship('client', 'first_name', 
       fn (Builder $query) => $query->groupBy('first_name')),


Thank you but that leads to an error because Builder::groupby() does not exist

@BillalBegueradj https://laravel.com/api/11.x//Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_groupBy

It should be work, I tried it in my own code. it works. Please check your file's top section for this file: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder

It seems your solution would work with groupBy. I am getting a different error at this stage and it is related to MySQL settings when using GROUP BY statement. So I can not test this approach for the moment. But I promise to come back to you after (and if) I figure out how to fix the related error message

I changed my database engine because my current one complains about an issue with `GROUP BY which should not exist given its version and default settings. So I accept and upvote your answer, it is valid.
